# Replace keys of one dictionary by the values of other

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries and want to join them with their keys, the output dictionary should have only values of both dictionaries

```
counter = Counter({0: 1702,
                 1: 1920,
                 2: 1851,
                 3: 1882,
                 4: 1745,
                 5: 1741,
                 6: 1827,
                 7: 1961,
                 8: 1790,
                 9: 1926})
labels = 
        {0: 'Tomato___Bacterial_spot',
         1: 'Tomato___Early_blight',
         2: 'Tomato___Late_blight',
         3: 'Tomato___Leaf_Mold',
         4: 'Tomato___Septoria_leaf_spot',
         5: 'Tomato___Spider_mites Two-spotted_spider_mite',
         6: 'Tomato___Target_Spot',
         7: 'Tomato___Tomato_Yellow_Leaf_Curl_Virus',
         8: 'Tomato___Tomato_mosaic_virus',
         9: 'Tomato___healthy'}
```

Output

```
 "Tomato___Bacterial_spot": 1920,
        "Tomato___healthy": 1926,
```

Comment: Are both dictionaries in correct order ?

Comment: order are same but it would be better if we can merge them with same key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter({0: 1702,
                   1: 1920,
                   2: 1851,
                   3: 1882,
                   4: 1745,
                   5: 1741,
                   6: 1827,
                   7: 1961,
                   8: 1790,
                   9: 1926})

labels = {0: 'Tomato___Bacterial_spot',
          1: 'Tomato___Early_blight',
          2: 'Tomato___Late_blight',
          3: 'Tomato___Leaf_Mold',
          4: 'Tomato___Septoria_leaf_spot',
          5: 'Tomato___Spider_mites Two-spotted_spider_mite',
          6: 'Tomato___Target_Spot',
          7: 'Tomato___Tomato_Yellow_Leaf_Curl_Virus',
          8: 'Tomato___Tomato_mosaic_virus',
          9: 'Tomato___healthy'}

res = {}
for k, v in labels.items():
    res[v] = counter[k]

print(res)
```

Or similarly you can use dictionary comprehension :

```
res2 = {v: counter[k] for k, v in labels.items()}
print(res2)
```